# Controller name is not being passed on ajax call on mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ajax call that has been working fine on a hosted website until recently

Defined like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'GetItemsForCountry',
        type: 'GET',
        data: "country=" + country,
        success: function (items) {
            $("#Items").empty();
            $("#Items").attr("disabled", false)
            $.each(items, function (i, c) {
                $("#Items").append($('<option></option>').val(c.Value).html(c.Text))
            }
                  );
        })
```

When I try and debug it locally in VS it's working fine and I see it passing my controller on the line...

```
http://localhost:9000/Home/GetItemsForCountry?country=USA
```

when I run it with it on the hosted server, it is being passed as

```
http://servername/GetItemsForCountry?country=USA.
```

It wasn't doing this before.

Does anyone have a clue why?   or know a way to MapRoute it to make this not give a 404 error?

Thanks for any help.

David

Comment: What URL is this being called from on the server? What about on localhost?

Comment: Hmmm.. it happens to be the home page simply the www.servername.com

Comment: If I put in the full url like www.servername.com/Home/Index  and then run it... it's fine and the ajax call doesn't fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the URL to `/home/getitemsforcountry` it will work on the server and locally. Just using `Getitemsforcountry` will attempt to tack that onto the current "area" of the site you are in.

Answer (score 0):

It's a relative URL that you're using so it's going to use what ever the current path is. Since it's a `home` url I'm assuming that it's also using the default route. It sounds like your localhost testing is going to `http://localhost:28347/home/index` instead of just the root url while your server test is going to the root url of `/`. One way to combat this is to use

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action= "GetItemsForCountry"})',
    type: 'GET',
    data: "country=" + country,
    success: function (items) {
        $("#Items").empty();
        $("#Items").attr("disabled", false)
        $.each(items, 
            function (i, c) {
                $("#Items").append($('<option></option>').val(c.Value).html(c.Text))
            }
        );
})
```

This should resolve the route for you regardless of the call.

Comment: I think it's because it's not resolving the url action before making the ajax call...       http://localhost:28347/Home/@Url.RouteUrl(new%20%7B%20controller%20=%20%22Home%22,%20action=%20%22GetItemsForCountry%22%7D)?country=USA

Comment: where is this call located? In a javascript file or on the page?

Comment: Ah, that explains it. You'll need to pass the computed to the function or set a variable to the right path via script on the page so that you can take advantage of the route helpers. They're not available in javascript. (or you can hard code your paths which isn't recommended)